# How do I set unicode-8 as the default in LibreOffice under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, libreoffice

When I use LibreOffice Calc and save my file as an .csv LibreOffice suggest Western Europe as default encoding. I however want unicode-8 encoding.

How do I set unicode-8 as the default in LibreOffice under Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my copy of LibreOffice v5.0.x, it doesn't seem to have a default setting. Looking around though, I found an example of a macro that you could use here to save in UTF8,

https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=19695

and the another macro to tell you use a File Picker dialog from

https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=36441

Here is complete code...

```
Function fOpenFile() as String

   Dim oFileDialog as Object
   Dim iAccept as Integer
   Dim sPath as String
   Dim InitPath as String
   Dim oUcb as object
   Dim filterNames(3) as String

   filterNames(0) = "*.csv"
   'filterNames(1) = "*.png"
   'filterNames(2) = "*.jpg"

   GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("Tools")
   'Note: The following services must be called in the following order,
   ' otherwise the FileDialog Service is not removed.
   oFileDialog = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.FilePicker")
   oUcb = createUnoService("com.sun.star.ucb.SimpleFileAccess")

   AddFiltersToDialog(FilterNames(), oFileDialog)
   'Set your initial path here!
   InitPath = ConvertToUrl("C:\")

   If oUcb.Exists(InitPath) Then
      oFileDialog.SetDisplayDirectory(InitPath)
   End If

   iAccept = oFileDialog.Execute()
   If iAccept = 1 Then
      sPath = oFileDialog.Files(0)
      fOpenFile = sPath
   End If
   oFileDialog.Dispose()

End Function
Sub SaveAsCsvUTF8
    Dim Propval(1) as New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    Propval(0).Name = "FilterName"
    Propval(0).Value = "Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)"
    Propval(1).Name = "FilterOptions"
    ' field sep(44 - comma), txt delim (34 - dblquo), charset (0 = system, 76 - utf8), first line (1 or 2) 
    Propval(1).Value = "44,34,76,1" 
    Doc = ThisComponent
    Filename = fOpenFile()
    FileURL = convertToURL(FileName)
    Doc.StoreAsURL(FileURL, Propval())
End Sub
```

Assign it to a shortcut and you are good to go.

PS: If the file is already in UTF8 it should just respect that.

HTH